# Collecting and converting date field for an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a date field in my model.

I'm trying to produce an array like this `[6/29/13, 6/27/13]`.

However, when I use `.collect` it returns an array like this `[Sat, 29 Jun 2013, Thu, 27 Jun 2013]`.

```
@dates = Todo.all.collect(&:date)
```

How can I iterate through all the database items and:

1. Convert the date to shorthand
2. Save everything into an array

I've tried making a method with `.strftime("%m/%d/%y")` but didn't have much luck.

Comment: `Todo.all.map { |todo| todo.date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") }` try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Todo.all.map { |todo| todo.date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") }
```